Is it possible to check on which server a repository has been cloned in bitbucket and github
Github seems to provide details of the git clones that have been run on a repository in it's Graphs -> traffic tabs. Is this information also available from either the github api or gh cli tools? I'm just interested in the git clone details, specifically the server it was cloned on.
Does Bitbucket provide something similar as well?
At first glance, having searched through the github/bitbucket api documentation, it doesn't seem like either api's expose this data, but am hoping I may have just not searched for it with the right keywords.

The GH API docs indicate this endpoint is available
curl -L \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>" \
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/traffic/clones

src: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/metrics/traffic?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-repository-clones

The BB Cloud API offers this endpoint
curl --request GET \
  --url 'https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo_slug}' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer <access_token>' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json'

src: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-repositories/#api-repositories-workspace-repo-slug-get

Thanks, I'll try out the BB api endpoint.
I just realised that neither the Github traffic tab in the UI nor the api endpoint include the hostname or ip address from which the clone was issued, which is really the main piece of data i'm looking for.
